# Using coroutine for timer, can't seem to get it working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator KillZombie() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(zombieDeathDelay); // waits for zombie corpse removal delay
    PhotonNetwork.Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Zombie Died");
    nm.zombieDied();
}
```

Im using that as a coroutine, but for some reason it never seems to actually execute the code to destroy my game object. I can't really figure out why, so any help would be great.

Comment: did you StartCoroutine(KillZombie()) ?

Comment: Make sure zombieDeathDelay is a value in seconds, so something like "1". It's possible to make a mistake like having it in milliseconds.

Comment: @wilson your script look OK--But if you still need unity timer script you should check this script i found on github!  **[unity timer](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2015/02/unity-timer-script-with-co-routine.html)**